# Writing a .plist based on tableView User Choice

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've got a tableView populated with twitter accounts that I want to write to a .plist when a user selects one. Currently, however, when I tap an account, it writes the textLabel.text of the bottom cell.

Here's my code.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


[testArray addObject:cell.textLabel.text];

NSArray *context = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Name", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *new = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:testArray forKeys:context];

[new writeToFile:writablePath atomically:YES];

}
```

Comment: Are you looking to have the whole table be written in the file?

Comment: No, just the selected cell's textLabel.text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where the `cell` object is being created at.  If you want to get the cell that was just selected, you can do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

This will allow you to grab the actual cell that the user 'touched'.